# Can't parse files uploaded in UTF-16 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, encoding, heroku, utf-8

I'm writing a Rails app that allows the user to upload TSV (Tab-separated values) files to be parsed on the server. Those files are encoded in UTF-16. All goes fine in local, but when I try to open the file with such encoding on Heroku, I'm getting a warning that says `warning: Unsupported encoding utf-16 ignored`. When later I try to read such file, it obviously fails stating `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`. See an excerpt of the code below:

```
    File.open(params[:batch_import][:file].path, 'r:utf-16') do |f|
      @recipients = Recipient.from_tsv(f.read)
    end
```

Is there any walkaround that I can do?

Answer (score 0):

UTF-16 files must be opened with the `binary` mode. Try this:

```
File.open(params[:batch_import][:file].path, 'rb:utf-16') do |f|
  @recipients = Recipient.from_tsv(f.read)
end
```

Comment: Sadly, that did not fix the problem : (